# Telerik Grid Row color

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Is the only way to change the background color of a row based on data on the Telerik grid by doing it in the ItemDataBound event?  I have a grid that a huge amount of data and it is taking a really long time.  I have a property in the data row that tells me what color the row needs to be.  I would like to be able to dynamically set the css class at runtime.

Thanks,

Rhonda

Comment: Rhonda: Yes, there's always a way to do this type of thing with javascript (better with JQuery). You'd need to find the specific element id on the HTML that's rendered on the page and change it's background color using javascript. Ot the flip side; how much data are you binding? If it's too much. perhaps it's better to implement pagination and get it on chunks.

Comment: I'm looking into paging right now.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to change the row color using `ItemStyle` and `AlternatingItemStyle`:

```
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
    <ItemStyle BackColor="PeachPuff" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to specifically change the style of the row during the OnItemDataBound event I recommend that you look at [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-appearance-conditional-formatting.html) from the Telerik online documentation. It covers how you can set inline styles from the code-behind, or use predefined CSS styles and apply them to the rows.